# Where place a init script for Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

Where is the best place for to put a init script in Sails.js?

I would like that this script is executed every time Sails is lifted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking for `config/bootstrap.js`?

Comment: It helped me. Thanks Sangharsh!